# How do you build an auto-generating menu for forums?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, nodes

I am using Drupal 7 with advanced forum and taxonomy menu and cannot figure out how to create a menu that will automatically add topics as menu items to forum containers with the right URL path structure. Taxonomy menu gets close but will not allow URLs other than taxonomy/term/[tid] (See: http://drupal.org/node/1161114). They need to generate in the pattern: forums/[container name]/[topic title]. I cannot seem to do this using the URL alias.

Has anyone built a drupal forum that generates a menu when topics are added and deleted that follow the standard forum URL path structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking back at this, I realize I was asking two questions:

1) How do you configure a URL alias pattern for a forum topic in the format: [forums]/[container_name]/[forum_topic_name]?

Install and enable [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto). Then configure a URL alias pattern at admin/config/search/path/patterns in this format [node:taxonomy-forums:parents]/[node:taxonomy-forums:name]/[node:title].

2) How do you then add this Forum topic to a menu underneath a specific parent automatically?

Install and enable [Menu Position](http://drupal.org/project/menu_position). Add a Menu Position rule at: admin/structure/menu-position/add for Content Type: Forum topic and select the menu parent item for Forum topics.